# Why does Spark dataset foreach method require explicit function conversion, but map does not?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Where `UserData.retrieve` is of type `(m: Map[String, String]) => User`
and `UserData.update` is of type `(r: spark.sql.Row) => Unit`

why does

`receipts map UserData.retrieve`

work fine, but when I run

`events foreach UserData.update`

it results in the following error:

`` missing argument list for method update in object UserData
Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected.
You can make this conversion explicit by writing `update _` or `update(_)` instead of `update`. ``

I see in the documentation that `map` expects `func: (T) ⇒ U` and `foreach` expects `f: (T) ⇒ Unit` so it seems to me that the compiler should convert my methods to functions for both `map` and `foreach`, but instead it only does so for `map`. Why?

n.b. I know that I can make this `foreach` call work by explicitly converting it,

`receipts.foreach.(UserData.update(_))`

but here I am asking for help understanding why I have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected.

foreach on Dataset is overloaded and may be called with ForeachFunction[T] or T => Unit.

The compiler does not have enough information to resolve which overloaded method is being called and therefore will not apply the function.

Comment: Shouldn't the compiler be able to detect that my method is a method and not a `ForeachFunction` trait, and thus be able determine which overloaded `foreach` method is being called?